# Make a menu collapsible

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make this woocommerce menu collapsible by hiding child items and show only when clicked, I would appreciate any help :

```
<!-- Categories Start -->
<h6>Categories</h6>

<div class="categories">
  <label class="category-filter" :key="'category_all'">
<input type="radio" name="category" v-model="category" value="" v-on:change="resetPagination();triggerFilter();" />
<span>All Products</span>
<!-- <span class="count" v-html="pagination.total_posts"></span> -->
</label>

  <div class="category-filter" v-for="categorySingle in categories" :key="'category_' + categorySingle.id">
    <div v-if="categorySingle.parent == 0">
      <!-- Outer category loop, only show parent categories (i.e.parent ID = 0) -->
      <!-- Details for parent category Start -->
      <label>
    <input type="radio" name="category" v-model="category" :value="categorySingle.id" v-on:change="resetPagination();triggerFilter();" />
    <span v-html="categorySingle.name"></span>
    <span class="count" v-html="categorySingle.count"></span>
  </label>
      <!-- Details for parent category End -->

      <!-- Loop through categories, if the category's parent ID matches the ID of the category in the outer loop, this category is a child of the outside category, so show Start -->
      <div v-for="categoryChild in categories" :key="'child_category_' + categoryChild.id" v-if="categoryChild.parent == categorySingle.id">
        <label class="ms-4 mt-2 d-block position-relative">
      <input type="radio" name="category" v-model="category" :value="categoryChild.id" v-on:change="resetPagination();triggerFilter();" />
      <span v-html="categoryChild.name"></span>
      <span class="count" v-html="categoryChild.count"></span>
    </label>
      </div>
      <!-- Loop through categories, if the category's parent ID matches the ID of the category in the outer loop, this category is a child of the outside category, so show End -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Categories End -->
</div>
<!-- Filters End -->
```

I tried hiding the dive and use jquery

Comment: Post the jquery that you have tried.

Comment: Hi ! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). BTW you can create a snippet that runs in StackOverflow with the `<>` button. If you provide the relevant code someone can certainly help.

Comment: People on SO are incredibly generous with their time, but you need to show that you have tried to solve your problem yourself. Describe what the context is, what solutions you have tried or where you have specifically run into problems.